# Parallelism control incremental variable

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task, parallel.foreach

I have the following `TPL` function:

```
int arrayIndex = 0;

Dictionary < string, int > customModel = new Dictionary < string, int > ();

    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>

        // process each employee holiday

        Parallel.ForEach < EmployeeHolidaysModel > (holidays,
            new ParallelOptions() {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Enviroment.ProcessorCount
            },
            item => {

                customModel.Add(item.HolidayName, arrayIndex);

                // increment the index
                arrayIndex++;

            })
    );

    //wait for all Tasks to finish
    Task.WaitAll(task);
```

The problem is that `arrayIndex` won't have unique values because of the Parallelism.

Is there a way I can control the `arrayIndex` variable so between parallel tasks the value is unique?

> Basically in my `customModel` I can't have a duplicate `arrayIndex` value.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: First: Why do you want to do this in parallel? Do you have enough holidays that you'll actually see a benefit to parallelism? For small data sets, the overhead of using multiple threads is far greater than the benefit you get from parallelizing the work.

Comment: I just place a sample, but there are a lot of calculations and is taking about 8 seconds to get the data. I need that to be faster

Comment: Why does your customModel object need to be a dictionary? Isn't it better to let the object keep track of the indices instead? It just looks weird having a string as a key and a index as value to me, but maybe you can elaborate it and explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three problems here:

1. You are writing to shared variables (both the int and the dictionary). This is unsafe. You must either synchronize or use thread-safe collections.
2. The amount of work that you're doing per iteration is so small that the overhead of parallelism will be multiple orders of magnitude bigger. This is not a good case for parallelism. Expect major slowdowns.
3. You start a task, then wait for it. What did you meant to accomplish doing that?

I think you need a basic [tutorial about threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). These are very basic issues. You won't be having fun using multi-threading at your current level of knowledge...

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use [Interlocked.Increment()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx). You should probably also use [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) to be safe, assuming that's not just sample-code you cooked up for the question.

Similarly, the Task isn't necessary here, since you're just waiting on it to finish filling `customModel`. Obviously, your scenario may be more complex.

But given the code you posted, I'd do something like:

```
int arrayIndex = 0;

ConcurrentDictionary<string,int> customModel
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<string,int>();

Parallel.ForEach<EmployeeHolidaysModel>(
    holidays,
    new ParallelOptions() {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Enviroment.ProcessorCount
    },
    item => customModel.TryAdd(
        item.HolidayName,
        Interlocked.Increment(ref arrayIndex)
    )
);

NowYouCanDoSomethingWith(customModel);
```